# Conways 99 graph problem

Tags: graph-theory, examples-counterexamples, conjectures

The Conway 99 graph problem is stated [here](https://oeis.org/A248380/a248380.pdf) as one of 5 problems.
My question is this: Is there somewhere a list of examples with "Conway graphs" with fewer then 99 vertices? Or can you provide examples with fewer than 99 vertices?

Definition of "Conway graph":
It is a simple undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ with the following property:

(1) $\forall (x,y) \in E: \exists ! z \in V: (x,z),(y,z) \in E$

(2) $\forall (x,y) \in E^c: \exists ! (z,w) \in V \times V: (x,z),(x,w),(y,z),(y,w) \in E$

(The definition is from here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.08047.pdf )

The Conway 99 graph problem asks if there exists a "Conway graph" with 99 vertices.

I am searching for examples of "small" Conway graphs.

**Edit:** 
Given the answer below, the next non trivial graph with 9 vertices is:
$G(2,1)$ 
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedQuadrangle.html

or the same graph:
$T(3,3)$:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TorusGridGraph.html

[This paper](https://pure.tue.nl/ws/files/2157517/593575.pdf) of Berlekamp might also be of interest where the graph with $243$ vertices is constructed.

Comment: Nice find of the Berlekamp paper! Hadn't seen that before...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know why people downvoted this question; it's perfectly valid and quite interesting to wonder why such a problem is listed by Conway and how difficult it might be.

[This](https://cp4space.wordpress.com/2018/03/11/a-rather-satisfying-winter/) blogpost by Adam Goucher discusses briefly at the start some of what led to the problem, before leading onto his discovery of [this lovely beast](https://b3s23life.blogspot.co.uk/2018/03/on-6-march-2018-first-member-of-new.html). You see from it that such graphs can only have $|V|\in\{3,9,99,243,6273,494019\}$ and that examples of 3, 9 and 243 vertices are indeed known (with the 243 vertex one being rather special!).

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you for your answer. it is very useful. thanks

Comment: Sorry to ask for this, but if my answer answered your question, could you accept it?

Comment: Yes, have accepted! Thanks.